# WPF Datagrid: Strange style behaviour

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xaml, datagrid

I have a weird behaviour in a datagrid control in WPF. Basically I add custom objects to a datagrid, which contains just one column. In this column I visualize an image and a textblock in a stackpanel. It works fine, until I define the width of the image. Then I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yq6xy.png).

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance!

Here is a code excerpt for the user control:

```xml
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Margin="2"
              CanUserResizeRows="False"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ItemsSource="{Binding dataGridRows}"
              SelectionChanged="selectionChanged"
              SelectionMode="Single"
              Style="{DynamicResource PaletteDataGrid}"
              ClipboardCopyMode="None"
              CanUserReorderColumns="False"
              CanUserResizeColumns="False"
              CanUserSortColumns="False"
              GridLinesVisibility="None"
              HeadersVisibility="None"
              HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
              RowStyle="{DynamicResource PaletteRowStyle}"
              CellStyle="{DynamicResource PaletteDataGridCell}">
        <DataGrid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="ScrollBar"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource ScrollBar}" />
        </DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image Source="{Binding itemImage}"
                                   MaxHeight="20"
                                   MaxWidth="20" />
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding itemName}"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Width="Auto"
                                       Margin="5, 0, 0, 0" />
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The styling template of the datagrid:

```xml
<Style x:Key="PaletteDataGrid"
       TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{StaticResource TabBackground}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{StaticResource TabItemActiveText}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="RowDetailsVisibilityMode"
            Value="VisibleWhenSelected" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode"
            Value="VerticalOnly" />
    <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled"
            Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                <Border BorderBrush="Transparent"
                        BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"
                        Background="{StaticResource TabBackground}"
                        Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="DG_ScrollViewer"
                                  Focusable="false">
                        <ScrollViewer.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ScrollViewer}">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="0" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <Button Command="{x:Static DataGrid.SelectAllCommand}"
                                            Focusable="false"
                                            Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=DataGridSelectAllButtonStyle, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                            Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.All}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                            Width="{Binding CellsPanelHorizontalOffset, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                                    <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter x:Name="PART_ColumnHeadersPresenter"
                                                                    Grid.Column="1"
                                                                    Visibility="Hidden" />
                                    <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                                            CanContentScroll="{TemplateBinding CanContentScroll}"
                                                            Grid.Column="2"
                                                            Grid.Row="1" />
                                    <ScrollBar x:Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar"
                                               Grid.Column="0"
                                               Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}"
                                               Orientation="Vertical"
                                               Grid.Row="1"
                                               Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                               Value="{Binding VerticalOffset, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                               ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}">

                                    </ScrollBar>
                                </Grid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </ScrollViewer.Template>
                        <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <MultiTrigger>
            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Property="IsGrouping"
                           Value="true" />
                <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping"
                           Value="false" />
            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll"
                    Value="false" />
        </MultiTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="PaletteRowStyle"
       TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">

    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate"
            Value="{x:Null}" />
    <Setter Property="ValidationErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Red"
                           Margin="2,0,0,0"
                           Text="!"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        CornerRadius="2"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                        Padding="5,5,5,5">
                    <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                                ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                        <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                                  Grid.Row="1"
                                                  SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                                  Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}" />
                        <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                           SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"
                                           Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
                    </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsNewItem"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Margin"
                    Value="{Binding NewItemMargin, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource TabBackground}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="1,1,1,1" />
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource ItemRolloverBackground}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="{StaticResource TabItemActiveBorder}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
                    Value="1,1,1,1" />
        </Trigger>

    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="PaletteDataGridCell"
       TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="0" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                 Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{StaticResource TabItemActiveText}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive"
                 Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{StaticResource TabItemActiveText}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                    Value="Transparent" />
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocusWithin"
                 Value="True">
        </Trigger>

        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                 Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Foreground"
                    Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

ScrollBar Style:

```xml
<Style x:Key="ScrollBarLineButton"
       TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border Name="Border"
                        Margin="1"
                        CornerRadius="2"
                        Background="{StaticResource TabItemActiveBorder}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItemActiveText}"
                        BorderThickness="1">
                    <Path HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                          Fill="{StaticResource TabItemActiveText}"
                          Data="{Binding Path=Content,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border"
                                Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource TabItemActiveBorder}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                             Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="{StaticResource DisabledForegroundBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ScrollBarPageButton"
       TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RepeatButton}">
                <Border Background="Transparent" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="ScrollBarThumb"
       TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Margin"
            Value="0,0,10,0" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="true" />
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Focusable"
            Value="false" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Thumb}">
                <Border CornerRadius="2"
                        Background="{StaticResource TabItemActiveBorder}"
                        BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItemActiveBorder}"
                        BorderThickness="1" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="VerticalScrollBar"
                 TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="0.00001*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Grid.RowSpan="1"
                CornerRadius="2"
                Background="{StaticResource TabBackground}"/>
            <Track Name="PART_Track"
               Grid.Row="1"
               IsDirectionReversed="true">
            <Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
                              Command="ScrollBar.PageUpCommand" />
            </Track.DecreaseRepeatButton>
            <Track.Thumb>
                <Thumb Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarThumb}"
                       Margin="1,0,1,0"
                       Background="{StaticResource TabItemInactiveBackground}"
                       BorderBrush="{StaticResource TabItemInactiveBackground}" />
            </Track.Thumb>
            <Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
                <RepeatButton Style="{StaticResource ScrollBarPageButton}"
                              Command="ScrollBar.PageDownCommand" />
            </Track.IncreaseRepeatButton>
        </Track>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>

<Style x:Key="ScrollBar"
       TargetType="{x:Type ScrollBar}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels"
            Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle"
            Value="true" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Orientation"
                 Value="Vertical">
            <Setter Property="Width"
                    Value="8" />
            <Setter Property="Height"
                    Value="Auto" />
            <Setter Property="Template"
                    Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollBar}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed that the effect goes away when I load items which overflow the current cell width. It seems that the cell defines its width according to the content (which is logical). But how can I define that the cell has a max width which doesn't exceed the datagrid boundaries and a min width which uses the whole datagrid width?

[Here][2] you see that the corner radius is only shown on the left side, not on the right because of the overflow.

**UPDATE 2**

The thing I want to achieve is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFA4N.png).

Additional information: The Datagrid is situated in a user control, which is bound to the content of a TabControl. Here is the code from the mainWindow.xaml:

```xml
    <Grid Margin="0,96,0,0">
        <TabControl ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource TabItem}"
                    TabStripPlacement="Right"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding loadedPalettes}"
                    Style="{StaticResource TabControl}"
                    Height="Auto"
                    SelectionChanged="paletteSelectionChanged"
                    SelectedIndex="{Binding selPaletteIndex}"
                    Width="Auto"
                    Margin="0,5,0,0">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}">
                        <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                            <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                        </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>

            <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                        <my:tabDataGrid />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: How will you explain this :  `<DataGrid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="ScrollBar"
                   BasedOn="{StaticResource ScrollBar}" />
                </DataGrid.Resources>`

Comment: Do you mean the code for the scroll bar style? I add to the thread above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the problem. It seems I messed up the row style template for the datagrid and forgot to give the `DataGridTemplateColumn` of the datagrid a defined width:

ScrollViewer in the datagrid row style template:

```xml
    <Setter Property="Template">
<Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <Border x:Name="DGR_Border"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                CornerRadius="2"
                SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                Padding="5,5,5,5">
            <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </SelectiveScrollingGrid.RowDefinitions>
                <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                        ItemsPanel="{TemplateBinding ItemsPanel}"
                                        SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1"
                                          Grid.Row="1"
                                          SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding AreRowDetailsFrozen, ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}"
                                          Visibility="{TemplateBinding DetailsVisibility}" />
                <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2"
                                   SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical"
                                   Visibility="{Binding HeadersVisibility, ConverterParameter={x:Static DataGridHeadersVisibility.Row}, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.HeadersVisibilityConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" />
            </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Setter.Value>
```

Datagrid columns definition in userControl.xaml

```xml
    <DataGrid.Columns>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Source="{Binding itemImage}"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       MaxHeight="20"
                       MaxWidth="20" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding itemName}"
                           Grid.Column="1"
                           Margin="5, 0, 0, 0" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Grid` instead of `StackPanel` inside of `DataTemplate`:

```
<DataGrid.Columns>
   <DataGridTemplateColumn>
       <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
             <Grid>        
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                   <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>            
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding itemImage}" MaxHeight="20" 
                       MaxWidth="20" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding itemName}"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Width="Auto"
                                   Margin="5, 0, 0, 0" />
             </Grid>
         </DataTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
   </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: Same effect, but i noticed something. I have attached the new image to the main post.

Comment: @ms_dos  you do not want a space between and `Border` of `DataGrid` and  `Image`?

Comment: I want that the border of the mouseOver trigger is always around the complete row. But when the content of the cell is to big for the current cell width, it stretches the cell width until the content fits. Even if the row is overflowing the boundaries of the datagrid. I updated the main post with additional information, maybe they help to solve my problem.